# Django: using variables as array indices?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templating

I am trying to create a template that will put items in a table.

**Controller:**

```
items = Item.all().order('name').fetch(10)

    template_values = {'items': items,
                       'headers': ['Name', 'Price', 'Quantity']}
    render('Views/table.html', self, template_values)
```

**Template:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for header in headers %}
        <th>{{header}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for item in items %}
        <tr><td><a href="detail/{{item.CSIN}}">{{item.name}}</a></td><td>{{item.CSIN}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Right now, the template is hard coded to look for certain attributes of `item`. I want to change this so it either looks for the attributes with the names that are in `headers`, or so that it looks for the first n attributes, where n is the length of `headers`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, why would you want to put template logic (which columns to display) in the view?

Comment: It chooses which columns to display based on what `header` is. This allows the template to be reused.

The choice of which columns to display is made in the controller, which tells the template through the `header` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tweak the view to do:

```
items = Item.all().order('name').fetch(10)
headers = ['Name', 'Price', 'Quantity']
viewitems = [[getattr(x, h) for h in headers] for x in items]

template_values = {'items': viewitems,
                   'headers': headers}
render('Views/table.html', self, template_values)
```

so all the template has to do is loop over each "item" (which will just be a list of the values to show corresponding to the headers.  Basically, this would move the logic (deciding what to show) from the template (or actually split a bit each in template and view) entirely to the Python code in the view, simplifying the template and making it more general, as you desire.

Comment: You could make the viewitems lazily evaluated, since they are perhaps db queries?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure you could -- use a genexp (round parentheses) rather than a listcomp (square brackets) for the outer level of `viewitems`.  But with the `fetch(10` (that was already in the OP's question) the time savings should be modest (if present at all: 10 DB queries vs a single 10-items query...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an existing template tag/filter that will accomplish what you want.  You could look into writing a custom template tag or filter which accepts the items list and the current header and returns the value after the look-up.  Have a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/.